# How would I put a closing quote image in the background of my style?

Tags: html, css

I figured out how to add an opening quote marks on my quote (using a background), but how would I add a closing quote marks in my style. I'd like to add a closing quote marks image after the Russell Wilson is a great quarterback.

If I'm not doing it the preferred way, can you suggest the best practices for making this happen?

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/huskydawgs/bmj942y4/2/)

```
<p>
    <span class="inline-quote">Russell Wilson is a great quarterback</span>
    Russell Carrington Wilson is an American football quarterback for the Seattle Seahawks of the National Football League. Wilson was selected by the Seahawks with the 12th pick in the third round of the 2012 NFL Draft.
</p>
```

```css
.inline-quote {
    background: url('http://www.pearl-guide.com/forum/images/Eloquent/miscblue/quote_icon.png') left top no-repeat;
    background-position: 15% 5px;
}
```

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/examples/Blockquotes/

Comment: I'm not sure you can put text in a background. You would need to create an image.

Answer (score 2):

You can only have one background per element. So make a pseudo-element!

```css
.inline-quote { position: relative }
.inline-quote::after { /* Insert it after */
    content: ''; /* Required for it to show up */
    position: absolute; /* Stretch it */
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    background: url('http://www.pearl-guide.com/forum/images/Eloquent/miscblue/quote_icon.png') left top no-repeat; /* Same background */
    background-position: 15% 90%; /* Position it in the lower right */
    transform: scaleX(-1); /* Flip it */
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bmj942y4/5/

You should also be using the [blockquote](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blockquote) element. http://jsfiddle.net/bmj942y4/7/

Comment: I already have a main blockquote css style element. If I want to add this style to another one, how would I call it something other than blockquote?

Comment: @user3075987 You can give it a class.

Answer (score 2):

you can use :before and :after

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bmj942y4/4/)

```css
.inline-quote:before, .inline-quote:after{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height:20px;
    background: url('http://www.pearl-guide.com/forum/images/Eloquent/miscblue/quote_icon.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    content: '';
}

.inline-quote:after{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Comment: The market share of browsers that implement the `-moz-` vendor prefix on transform is very low.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiples background-image
**Example**

```
background-image: url('img1.jpg'), url(img2.jpg);
background-position: 15% 5px, 85% 5px;
```

**Work with**

- Firefox 3.6+
- Safari 1+
- Chrome 1.3+
- Explorer 9+
- Opera 10.5+

**More informations**
http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

Comment: How would you flip it?

Comment: I wouldn't, I would use a second image.

Comment: Another HTTP request just for that? Think of the mobile users…

Comment: I understand your point of view. I believe both answers are good. The question is: What's the priority? Code performance or Code readability.

Comment: Depends on the application. But in any case, a pseudo-element is intuitive enough, so readability isn't a huge issue.